# Where is the P2 laboratory in 'Pokemon Black 2'?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-black-2-white-2

Where is the P2 laboratory in Black 2? And any tips on beating the Scientist there?

Comment: If my answer worked for you, you can always accept the answer by clicking the 'tick' on the question above. Doing so will allow the community to know that my answer worked for you so that if they were to face the same problem, they may react accordingly. In addition, both of us will receive some reputation points. A WIN-WIN! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> P2 Laboratory (or P2 Lab) is a small island with a lab on it. It's
>   located in South Eastern Unova. The only way to reach it is by going
>   West on the Southern half of Route 17, North on Route 18, and East on
>   the Northern half of Route 17.
>
> Inside the Lab is a Scientist. If you have a Genesect, the Scientist
>   will challenge you to a battle.

**TAKE NOTE:** The following are the Pokémon that the Scientist will use. There is also a chance of him using an X-Special in the battle.

The Scientist may use an **[X-Special](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-black-white-version-2/Battle_Hold_Items)** in this single battle.

**[Klink](http://www.ign.com/pokedex/pokemon/klink) ||| [Klang](http://www.ign.com/pokedex/pokemon/klang)**
**Level:** 34
**Type:** Steel
**Ability:** Plus or Minus
**Hold Item:** N/A

```
      Moves
```

- [**Gear Grind**](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-black-white-version-2/Gear_Grind)
- [**Bind**](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-black-white-version-2/Bind)
- [**Charge Beam**](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-black-white-version-2/Charge_Beam)
- [**Autotomize**](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-black-white-version-2/Autotomize)

> After the battle, he'll give you two Drives for Genesect's Techno
>   Blast. The drives depends on which version you're playing. Black 2
>   gives you the Burn Drive and Shock Drive. White 2 gives you the Chill
>   Drive and Douse Drive.
>
> A Dubious Disc can be picked up in the back of the room.

All this with reference to: [LINK](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-black-white-version-2/P2_Laboratory)